# HTML form returning raw PHP code

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form and I would like the contents to be mailed to an email address, the problem I'm having is that anytime I hit the submit button, the page just shows the raw PHP code and no email is being sent. I took out the email address, but I just have a yahoo account in there now for testing purposes. I am running this locally through WAMP with wordpress installed and have no issues with Wordpress. Any thoughts?

**HTML**

```
<form id="signup" autocomplete="on" method="post" name="contactform" action="http://localhost/contact-form-handler.php">
<div id="prayerRequest"></div><!-- END prayerRequest -->
<textarea class="text" name="prayer" placeholder="* Prayer Request" required=""></textarea><br>
<select name="title" class="dropDown" required="">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">* Title</option>
    <option value="Mr">Mr.</option>
    <option value="Ms">Ms.</option>
    <option value="Mrs">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Dr">Dr.</option>
    <option value="Rev">Rev.</option>
    <option value="Pastor">Pastor</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="multiple" name="first" placeholder="* First Name" required="">
<input type="text" class="multiple" name="last" placeholder="* Last Name" required=""><br>
<input type="email" class="full" name="email" placeholder="* Email Address" required=""><br>
<input type="text" class="full" name="address" placeholder="* Street Address 1" required="">
<input type="text" class="full" placeholder="Street Address 2"> 
<input type="text" class="multiple" name="city" placeholder="* City" required="">
<button type="submit" class="submit">Submit Prayer Request</button>
<p>*Required Field</p>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'myemail@domain.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['first'])  || 
empty($_POST['email']) || 
empty($_POST['prayer']))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['first']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['prayer']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
$to = $myemail; 
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $first \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n        $prayer"; 

$headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact form handler</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running this on a server with a PHP interpreter?

Comment: either you don't have php installed, or it's misconfigured. a properly configured server would execute that php, not return the raw code.

Comment: I am running this locally with WAMP. Sorry, I forgot to include that. The site Im am making is running in Wordpress and the PHP functions from Wordpress works fine. I will update my original question to reflect this.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is you don't have the server setup to parse php on the file extension you are using...usually you add something like " AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm " to .htaccess

Comment: You file extension should be set to `.php` in order for the server to parse it correctly.

Comment: Question about the action field:

If I have my file structure as C:/wamp/www/php/contact-form-handler.php my action field should read http://localhost/php/contact-form-handler.php right?

Comment: Update*

I added 
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .php .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .php .htm
to .htaccess and now it downloads the php form when you submit.

Comment: you should not use absolute paths - try "/contact-form-handler.php"

Comment: just to confirm: you're running it locally, via a `http://` URL (eg http://localhost/...), correct? Please confirm that you're not just opening the file from the desktop or anything like that. (I know it's obvious, but sometimes the most obvious things do get missed)

Comment: I think i have it figured out. Its returning the thank you page now. I had to add  Just need to configure my php ini file to route smtp traffic. I added:
AddType text/html .php .php4 .php5 .phps
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php4 .php5
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

to the .htaccess file and it seems to work now.

Comment: It's working now. Configured smtp in the php.ini file to redirect to a mailserver. Editing the .htacess file worked. Thanks everyone!